# Problem in parsing nested tags in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I have an xml that i am parsing through DOM parser. the xml is of somewhat this sequence

```
 <root>
   <item1> abc </item1>
   <item2> def </item2>
   <item3> ghi </item3>
   <item4>
        <subItem4>
              <name> xyz </name>
              <id>   1  </id>
        </subItem4>
        <subItem4>
              <name> asd </name>
              <id>   2  </id>
        </subItem4>
   </item4>
</root>
```

According to this dummy xml i am reaching till subItem 4 but not to the childern of it. what i am trying is as follows to get innermost Items is:

NodeList slide = theElement.getElementsByTagName("item4").item(0).getChildNodes();

```
        for(int i = 0; i<slide.getLength(); i++)
        {
            NodeList subSlides = theElement.getElementsByTagName("subItem4").item(0).getChildNodes();

                for (int j=0; j<subSlides.getLength(); j++)
                {
                    String subSlide_title   = subSlides.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();             

                }
        }
```

its not working. please can someone identify where am i doing the mistake in parsing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using valid XML - you can't have spaces in tag names.

XML Names cannot contain white space, see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#xml-names) for valid values.

---

Update (following comment that the posted sample is representative of the actual XML):

Your access via the indexer of the node list is incorrect:

```
String subSlide_title = subSlides.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

Try this instead (using `j` instead of `i`, as the inner loop variable is called):

```
String subSlide_title = subSlides.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

Comment: i know that this is not actual. i have intentionally given spaces they are not in original xml.

Comment: @Usama - If you don't give a representative example, how can anyone help?

Comment: i have edited and removed the spaces now tell me. i cannot post original xml here thats y posted a dummy of same pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
 for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
     Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
     NodeList nodesimg = element.getElementsByTagName("name");
     for (int j = 0; j < nodesimg.getLength(); j++) {
        Element line = (Element) nodesimg.item(j);
        String value=getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
     }
}
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
  Node child = e.getFirstChild();
  if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
     CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
     return cd.getData();
  }
  return "?";
}
```

I think above code will help you in parsing xml file.

Answer (score 1):

The XML elements are all messed up. 
There are literally 2 lines that don't have mistakes in them.

For instance

```
<subItem 4>
```

is syntactically wrong and I don't see what logical sense you could make out of it.

Do you mean

```
<subItem4>
```

as in the fourth sub item or

```
<subItem someAttribute="4">
```

I'd recommend learning XML, it's very simple... http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp

Comment: @soBinary..I have removed all unnecessary spaces, now  please suggest something...